# Clearing data context on error?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm working on a program that uses Linq-to-SQL.  There is a method in the program that bombs out because it's attempting to write a record with a duplicate key.  I've added a try/catch on the `context.SubmitChanges()` and I'm logging the error so I can check it out later.  My problem, though, is that since the insert didn't happen, the data context still has the 'bad' data in it.  Is there a way I can clear the context?

Comment: I would throw it away and create a new one.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Yeah, that seems the best way to deal with this.  I looked at some other solutions to this question on Google and almost all of them say what you say.  I was hoping there was a neat "ClearContext(datacontext)" command.  Ah well, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  Basically, all I had to do was remove the offending data from the data context by using the `DeleteOnSubmit()` method of the context.  All I had to do was supply which data object in the context I wanted to delete:

`dataContext.DeleteOnSubmit(offendingData);`